# jQuery .hover not toggling class, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, hover, jquery-hover

```
<li class="animated aButton"><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
```

```js
$('.aButton').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('shake');
  }
);
```

I am trying to add the class shake from animate css on hover, but it is not working, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the entire html page so we can see the script tag, jquery version ect

Comment: [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/pod6kcza/) .. provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working.

```js
$('.aButton').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('shake');
  }
);
```

```css
.shake {
  color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="animated aButton"><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work

Jquery

```
$('.aButton').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('shake');
  }
);
```

CSS

```
.shake{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the working sample:https://jsfiddle.net/mqdfdkxv/